# What are the devices that Stryker's team use

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In [**X-Men: Apocalypse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse), after the **X-Mansion** (Xavier’s School for Gifted Youngsters) was incinerated by a blast and (almost) everyone was saved by Quiksilver, General Stryker arrives with his team and seizes the opportunity to capture Mystique and a few other mutants.

He did so by first knocking every mutant unconscious, and he does so by using something that originated from either the helicopter and/or the big gun-like things held by his soldiers.

[image]

**Question: *What is the device or technology* on the helicopter and/or guns that he uses to knock down all the mutants, and *how did it only manage to knock everyone, but leave Jean Grey, NightCrawler and Cyclops unaffected* when they were in virtually the same space as the others?**

Comment: The latter is easy. They were farther away, in the ruins of the school, and walls were in the way.

Comment: Okay, how about the devices/tech used??

Comment: If I knew both, I'd answer :) But they are pretty self-explanatory. Stun net guns. affects anyone mutant or not (moira was affected IIRC) inside the area of effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated earlier, the guns are an area-of-effect type field, and only apply in the region they are aimed at. Scott, Jean, Kurt are too far away for them to affect them. The soldiers are likewise unaffected. It also applied to more than just mutants, as Moira was affected.

In the concept art for the weapons, they are simply labeled Stun Guns. And there were hand gun versions as well, not just rifles/cannons.

http://comicbook.com/marvel/2016/09/09/x-men-apocalypse-concept-art-for-cyclops-nightcrawler-professor-/

[image]

They were previously disk launchers that used "knock out energy" depicted as electric bolts. This was modified in the final film, keeping the general concept of the guns aimed up and the energy raining down.

Answer (score 0):

Cyclops ran to the ruins of the mansion after learning that Havoc was too close to the explosion and probably died. Jean and Nightcrawler followed him. They were way out of reach and sight of Striker's team and clear from the zone covered by the attack.

What the gun was is not a can-be-this-and-this-alone situation. It is a stun gun. Probably sonic based. Idea of using [sonic fictional guns has always been an interest for science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon#In_fiction_and_popular_culture) and Marvel is no exception (and maybe even a pioneer.)

Comment: Thats...  not a sonic effect.

Comment: Hence *"probably"*